# Laravel Call to undefined method Serahk\MyPackage\MyPackageServiceProvider::isDeferred()

Tags: laravel

Am trying to create a new package and use it with Laravel. For now it is just simple with just the service provider that only loads the routes file and the views which only has one view.
In my routes file, I am only returning this view.

I have added this package into my main project composer.json file as below in repositories section and the require section:

Repositories section

```
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "/home/serahk/Documents/packages/mypackage"
    }
```

require section: `"serahk/mypackage": "dev-main"`

Then run `composer update` and now get the error below that the method isDeffered is not defined in my service provider.
My service provider does not have this method at all, I am not quite sure where laravel is getting this from. Below is my basic service provider:

```
<?php

namespace Serahk\MyPackage;

class MyPackageServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/route.php');
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/views', 'serahk/mypackage');
    }

    public function register()
    {

    }
}
```

Have tried running composer dump but still getting the same error.
I have also removed vendor and composer.lock and tried re-installing again but still getting the same error*your text*